# How to get header value from cxf component using apache camel?

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel

I wanted to log http response code. My code looks like this:

```
        onCompletion()
                .log("${in.header.operationName}" + " - " + "${in.header.CamelHttpResponseCode}");

        from(
                cxf("/test")
                        .wsdlURL("wsdl/wsdl.wsdl")
                        .serviceClass("org.tempuri.Class")
                        .dataFormat(DataFormat.POJO)
                        .advanced().schemaValidationEnabled(true)
        )
                .to(direct("route"));
```

Why does camel not see the response code in header?

The result I expect is log with http status. For example:
`OperationName - 200`

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Camel, when using the CXF component, the response code is not directly available in the headers after invoking a web service. The response code is usually part of the HTTP response message, and you can access it using the `CamelHttpResponseCode` property of the message body.

To log the HTTP response code in your example, you need to modify your code slightly. Here's an updated version that should log the expected result:

```java
from(
    cxf("/test")
        .wsdlURL("wsdl/wsdl.wsdl")
        .serviceClass("org.tempuri.Class")
        .dataFormat(DataFormat.POJO)
        .advanced().schemaValidationEnabled(true)
)
    .to(direct("route"))
    .onCompletion()
        .log("${in.header.operationName} - ${in.body[CamelHttpResponseCode]}");
```

In the updated code, the `onCompletion` block is placed after the `to` statement, so it will execute after the response is received. The `${in.body[CamelHttpResponseCode]}` expression accesses the `CamelHttpResponseCode` property from the message body, which should contain the HTTP response code.

By logging `${in.header.operationName} - ${in.body[CamelHttpResponseCode]}`, you will get the desired log output, such as "OperationName - 200", with the operation name and the corresponding HTTP response code.